# Get the total discount using a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that computes the discount of each item. Now I want is get the total of the discount. How can I do that?

My query to compute the discount is:

```
select (dla.unit_list_price + dla.unit_selling_price) * dla.ordered_qty as discount
       , dla.itemname as item_name 
 from doo_lines_all dla
```

For example, below is the returned data of the query I did.

```
Item_Name        Discount
Item1            50
Item2            25
Item3            30
```

Now I want is to get the total discount which I expected result is `105`

Comment: how it should look like? where the total value should be ? in a new row , i the third column?

Comment: In the 3rd column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to forego the item name:

```
select sum((dla.unit_list_price + dla.unit_selling_price) * dla.ordered_qty) as totaldiscount
from doo_lines_all dla
```

This will produce just a single output (one row, one column) of "105"

If you want to keep the item name in there and have the lines show the individual discount and a repeating total we can use an analytic:

```
select 
  dla.itemname,
  (dla.unit_list_price + dla.unit_selling_price) * dla.ordered_qty as discount,
  sum((dla.unit_list_price + dla.unit_selling_price) * dla.ordered_qty) over() as totaldiscount

from doo_lines_all dla
```

This will produce an output like:

```
Item_Name        Discount  TotalDiscount
Item1            50        105
Item2            25        105
Item3            30        105
```

There are other ways of achieving the same thing but an analytic function is perhaps the simplest to write, though perhaps harder to understand than doing this:

```
select 
  dla.itemname,
  (dla.unit_list_price + dla.unit_selling_price) * dla.ordered_qty as discount,
  t.totaldiscount

from doo_lines_all dla
cross join
(
  select sum((unit_list_price + unit_selling_price) * ordered_qty) as totaldiscount
  from doo_lines_all
) t
```

This works out the total in a subquery and then joins it to every row from dla via a cross join. You could conceive that it works the same as the analytic/it's one way to think of how the analytic works

Comment: Thanks on this! I got the answer that I want! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome; one of the most useful functions I ever learned in oracle was the analytics - definitely something to look into!

Answer (score 1):

[Sum](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm) the query:

```
select sum((dla.unit_list_price + dla.unit_selling_price) * dla.ordered_qty) as discount
       , dla.itemname as item_name 
 from doo_lines_all dla
```

> SUM returns the sum of values of expr.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the "SUM" function
like this

```
SUM((dla.unit_list_price + dla.unit_selling_price) * dla.ordered_qty) as discount
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`SUM`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sum-analytic-function#sum) analytical function

```
with tab as(
  select 'item1' as item , 50 as discount from dual union all
  select 'item2' as item , 25 as discount from dual union all
  select 'item3' as item , 30 as discount from dual 
)
select t.*
     , sum(t.discount) OVER () AS total_discount
from tab t;
```

> ```
> ITEM  | DISCOUNT | TOTAL_DISCOUNT
> :---- | -------: | -------------:
> item1 |       50 |            105
> item2 |       25 |            105
> item3 |       30 |            105
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e1f092b46fcd516190fabe83448e37b7)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grouping sets`

```
with doo_lines_all( discount, item_name ) as
(
 select 50, 'Item1' from dual union all
 select 25, 'Item2' from dual union all
 select 30, 'Item3' from dual
)
select item_name, 
       sum( discount ) as discount 
  from doo_lines_all dla
 group by grouping sets(item_name,())
 order by item_name;

ITEM_NAME   DISCOUNT
---------   --------
Item1       50
Item2       25
Item3       30
            105
```

to return the sum of discounts as a seperate row.